# How do i update a dataframe with values obtained from running a loop

Tags: dataframe, keras

Currently running a keras model, for analysis of the final outputs from changes in algorithm parameters i'm trying to run the model inside the loops and update a dataframe with the required output (loss)

refer to the code.

outputs an empty dataframe with columns names

```
epochs = [1,5,10,15,20,25,30]
batch_sizes = [64,128,256,512]
modeldata = pd.DataFrame()

for e in epochs:
    
    modeldata['Epochs'] = e
    
    for bs in batch_sizes:
        
        modeldata['Batch Size'] = bs
    
        training = mod_nvp.fit(
        x_train, y_train,    
        batch_size = bs, 
        epochs = e,
        validation_split = 0.2,
        verbose = 0
    )
        y_pred = mod_nvp.predict(x_test, verbose = 0) 
        
        modeldata['Loss'] = custom_loss_nvp1(y_test,y_pred)

        #modeldata['Training Loss'] = np.sum(training.history['loss'])
        #modeldata['Test Loss'] = np.sum(training.history['val_loss'])
    
        print('current running epoch',e,'with batchsize',bs)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

made this edit to the code, which does the required job

```
for e in epochs:

    for bs in batch_sizes:

        training = mod_nvp.fit(
        x_train, y_train,    
        batch_size = bs, 
        epochs = e,
        validation_split = 0.2,
        verbose = 0
       )
        y_pred = mod_nvp.predict(x_test, verbose = 0) 
    
        #train_loss = np.sum(training.history['loss'])
        #test_loss = np.sum(training.history['val_loss'])
    
        inv_cost = custom_loss_nvp1(y_test,y_pred)
    
        l = pd.DataFrame([e, bs, inv_cost, train_loss, test_loss])
    
        modeldata = pd.concat([modeldata,l], axis=1)
    
        #print('trained epoch-',e,'with batch size-',bs)
```